# max length of file name

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager, nsdocumentdirectory

i am using the code below to save an image in the `NSDocumentDirectory`

```
-(BOOL)saveImage:(UIImage *)image name:(NSString *)name{

    NSString *dir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
    NSString *path = [NSString pathWithComponents:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:dir, name, nil]];

    BOOL ok = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:path contents:nil attributes:nil];

    if (!ok) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating file %@", path);
    } 
    else {
        NSFileHandle* myFileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath:path];
        [myFileHandle writeData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];
        [myFileHandle closeFile];
    }
    return ok;
}
```

the name is usually the url of where the image was downloaded.

is there a constraint on the length of the file name? you know sometimes urls may be super long...

thank you

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Taking a look at the PATH_MAX constant in syslimits.h:91

```
... 
#define PATH_MAX         1024   /* max bytes in pathname */
...
```

You can test this yourself by doing :

```
NSLog(@"%i", PATH_MAX);
```

just to make sure.

Comment: It's also worth noting the length of the filename component of a path - in the same header `#define NAME_MAX 255`.

Comment: This should be included in the answer

Comment: In practise it may be wise to stay somewhat below PATH_MAX for paths to intra-app resources according to [this post](https://deciphertools.com/blog/2014_10_01_beware_of_long_pathnames/).   It suggests 932 characters as a working maximum, as apparently the use of intermediate directories during an iTunes/iCloud backup operation can cause the total path length to exceed PATH_MAX, resulting in failure to backup/restore your app.

Comment: @user2067021 Thanks for sharing that post! Just one clarification after clicking/reading through your linked post: the recommended working maximum is actually  PATH_MAX - 7, or 1017. The 932 number is characters in the filename after the app sandbox, which is typically 85. So according to that, it should be safe to use PATH_MAX - 7 or 1017 to maintain support for iCloud backups.